# Actualizar un div automáticamente

Tags: php, javascript

estoy intentando actualizar una imagen cada cierto tiempo, en este caso cada 10 minutos por si la imagen cambia, pero no logro que me funcione.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#hora").load(1000);

    });

</script>

<!--Mostramos la hora-->
<div id="hora"><?= date('H:i:s'); ?></div>
```

Comment: Y si pruebas con setInterval

Comment: Si puedes decirme como, ya que estoy matándome aprendiendo JavaScript.

Comment: Por si la imagen cambia, pero en que sentido cambiaria, en el nombre o mantendria este pero se modificaria el contenido???

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images

Comment: Se modificaría el contenido, por eso estoy enviando a actualizar la imagen, que si yo cambio la imagen, se actualice, pero se actualizaría cada 10 minutos.

Answer (score 0):

para dicha function setInterval seria la solucion te propongo este pequeño ejemplo de como funciona asi tendras una mejor idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


var inter;//declarar una variable para el intervalode tiempo
var count=0;//una variable que cuente los segundos o minutos
var img=$("#img");//obtener imagen

//crear el intervalo
inter=setInterval(function(){

$(".remaining").html(count++)//agragar contador al DOM
  

if(count==10){

    img.attr("src","https://elgeekman.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cursos-sobre-programacion.jpg")
  count=0;
  //clearInterval(inter);//parar intervalo de tiempo
   
   
}


},1000)


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<img src="https://concepto.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/algoritmo-min-e1523301106897.jpg" id="img" width="100px">

<p class="remaining"></p>
```

en este caso hice que en 10 segundo cambie la imagen ojala y te sirva de algo

Comment: Hola, yo sólo deseo actualizar el div nada más :/